# Chrome opens text instead of PDF with some blobs from Azure

Tags: angular, azure, google-chrome, pdf, blob

I'm working on an Angular app and I have the following code for opening blob content in the browser or downloading it (including a workaround for Edge):

```
if (openFile) {
    // Open blobs in new tab
    window.open(URL.createObjectURL(myBlob), "_blank");
} else {
    // Edge workaroud for downloading file
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(myBlob, file.name);
    } else {
        let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = fileURL;
        a.download = filenameFromHeader;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
    }
}
```

As you can see the app let users to open blobs in a new tab of the browser, instead of downloading them, according on which button they click on.

This works like a charm, with all browsers, both opening and downloading (except opening blobs in Edge that is blocked for security reasons).

The problem is that I have 2 Azure environments and only in one of them opening file works always with every PDF file.
In the other environment, with **some** PDF files, Chrome opens a tab with the binary content of the PDF, instead of opening it.

Here is the `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` in the response header coming from both Azure environments:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myDocument.pdf'
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

So, since the Angular app is the same, the PDF files are the same, the Chrome browser used is the same, what could be wrong with one of the Azure environments that with **some** PDF files the corresponding blob is shown as text instead of PDF?

Comment: Did you verify that when the file arrives in your application the headers are still the same as you set them?  (for the non-working version)?  Also, if you use `Content-Type : application/pdf` do you see any change for the non-working.

Comment: possible permission issue with the files? I would try to move the file or reupload to see if the file has permission issues or corrupt.

Comment: @jcuypers Yes, the headers are still the same. About changing `Content-Type` to `application-pdf` I have to test it. Anyway if it should work this doesn't make me to figure out what could be wrong with non-working Azure.

Comment: @AnassKartit It's not a permission or corruption issue, because I have made several tries uploading the same files, and with some works and with other doesn't work.

Comment: @smartmouse yes I agree, but it would be better to have some clue (although no direct solution), then have no clue.  It could for example confirm inconsistency in back-end environment.   can you please confirm that both azure environments are exact copies (1:1) with identical sofware / versioning and access to the same data files etc ...